# How to pass PHP variable to trigger table?

Tags: php, sql

I have two tables, lets say table1 and table2.The second table is a trigger from table1. table1 has two fields (id, comment) and triggered table which is table2 has 3 fields (id, comment,session_id) mysql statement in the PHP page is "INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ( 1,"HELLO") . According to the created trigger this statement also affects tabl2 by inserting those values to it. But I want to pass another variable which is session_id with this statement to be inserted to triggered table.Is it possible to do it? if Yes, How?

Comment: Yes I think so, but your question is not very clear. Can you demonstrate what you actually mean with some example code or some inputs and outputs

Comment: Also please dont SPAM tags. They are used to attract the correct audience for you question, if you add the wrong tags, you run the risk of getting downvotes

Comment: Could you expand your question to include a minimal reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: For example , table1 has two fields (id, comment) and triggered table which is table2 has 3 fields (id, comment,session_id) my sql statement in the PHP page is "INSERT INTO table1 VALUES  ( 1,"HELLO") . According to the created trigger this statement also affects tabl2 by inserting those values to it. But I want to pass another variable which is session_id with this statement to be inserted to triggered table.

Comment: Please update your question with the clarification so people don't have to read the comment chain.

Comment: Thanks a lot . I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will depend heavily on which features are supported by your database engine (you don't mention which one you use).

Most RDBMS engines support [user variables.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) These should, in principle, be visible to the trigger.

So, you could do something like

```
SET @session_id = 'A123o0oC';
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ( 1,"HELLO");
```

Your trigger should then be able to access @session_id, and include that in the insert statement.